# Double Quotes in Inline CSS in HTML Email are getting escaped

Tags: php, css, html-email, mailgun

I have setup a basic email marketing program using php based on the mailgun api. Now whenever I send emails from the program, all the double quotes in the inline CSS of the HTML email get escaped. So I end up with an ugly html email with the table borders and the text showing up  and not much else.

But when I try sending the exact same html email through the same program through my localhost, the email with proper html formatting and CSS gets delivered.

Why is this happening? How do I solve this?

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background:#efefef; height:auto; width:100%">
```

On my hosted website, the above gets displayed as follows:

```
<table align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"background:#efefef; height:auto; width:100%\">
```

But, when I send the same email through my localhost, there is no problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but it looks like there are some tricks to using Mailgun. One of them seems to be to...

> 3. use stripslashes() to escape data before trying to send it (HTML, anyways).

Source: [Sending an email through Mailgun with PHP (Part 2)](http://stevesohcot.com/tech-lessons-learned/2012/11/01/sending-an-email-through-mailgun-with-php-part-2/)